# Best practices for using built in Membership Provider

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am creating a custom site using the default membership provider, MVC5, EF6.1.1 using Code First.

The question I have is, what is the best way to link the two user tables? Should I have 2 databases? Should I just build my application into the database for the membership provider? And if that is the case, is there an easy way or a method to extract the GUID that is created when a new user registers to map a foreign key to my user table?

I guess I would rather keep the two separate and not have to deal with writing a custom provider, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the most logical way to do this.

Thanks!
Tony

Comment: Membership is deprecated and replaced with identity in MVC 5. Do you mean to say you are using identity instead?

Comment: Sorry, yes Identity. Thanks!